# R extended summary numerical values including kurtosis, skew, etc?

Tags: r, statistics

Is there a one-liner in R that will give me the following stats for each numerical column of a dataframe?

`count, mean, median, q3, q1, iqr, mode, min, max, antimode, pstdev, sstdev, pvar, svar, mad, madraw, pskew, sskew, pkurt, skurt, dpo, jarque`

Something like an extended method of `summary(dt)`? Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/descriptives.html

Comment: Psych describe seems to be the best option

Comment: There is also a package called `moments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `describe()` method in the [psych](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html) package does include kurtosis and skew:

`dt = data.frame(a=rnorm(1000),b=rnorm(1000))
library(psych)
describe(dt)`

`vars    n mean   sd median trimmed  mad   min  max range  skew kurtosis   se
a    1 1000    0 1.01      0    0.01 1.00 -3.59 3.36  6.95 -0.06     0.17 0.03
b    2 1000    0 0.97      0    0.00 0.93 -3.15 3.10  6.25 -0.08    -0.07 0.03`